# Nav collapsing and closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building some website and I want to have menu like on http://www.strv.com (with transition effect on open and close).

I've already done code like:

```
<div class="menu">
    <button id="hamburger" type="button" class="btn pull-left navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <button id="hamburger" class="btn pull-left">
        <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="list-inline nav-menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="mainmenu">
    <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="close btn btn-default navbar-toggle">Close</button>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li><a href="#">Subitem1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subitem2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subitem3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subitem4</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eztuhvhL/
(not working there and don't know why), but there is no transition effect on close and I can't solve it.

And also I want to do add "Item1, Item2, Item3" to this menu on mobile screens and I don't know how to figure it out.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide your code so we can see what you have tried.

Comment: updated, there is a link on JSFiddle. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have two buttons with the id hamburger so jquery doesn't know which one you want. If you look at the console for like chromes devtools, you will see that nothing happens when you click it. The solution is to get rid of the first instance of hamburger. Here is what I got:

http://codepen.io/Squeakasaur/pen/mWKzer

```
<div class="menu">


            <button id="hamburger" class="btn pull-left">
                <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="list-inline nav-menu">
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
                <li class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div id="mainmenu">
            <div class="container">
                <button type="button" class="close btn btn-default navbar-toggle">Close</button>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    <li><a href="#">Subitem1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Subitem2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Subitem3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Subitem4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>


  </div>
```

That should fix your problem. You can also just change the id of the first instance to something else :P

Comment: this code is not working only on jsfiddle, but there is no my issue, but thanks

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are saying. Are you saying that it isn't working in jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/Squeakasaur/eztuhvhL/1/

Comment: No, my code doesn't work on jsfiddle, but anyway I just only want to find solution how to have menu like strv.com :)

Comment: If you are using Chrome you could do inspect element and pick apart their nav.